# lsof: home folder is busy, but I never logged in as that user

Tags: arch-linux, encryption, lsof

I'm trying to run [ecryptfs-migrate-home](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Encrypting_a_home_directory) to encrypt my home folder, but the command keeps failing the [open files](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/ecryptfs-utils/commit/13b0bf8caba0e69b5e847c8d6baee4afe33d347d#diff-3c81cc743c45880b3b8c74c1be79a7c6R128) check.

Indeed, `lsof +D "/home/will"` shows the same in-use files as `encrypt-migrate-home`...but...I never logged in as `will`!  I only logged in as `root` (No window system, terminal only).  I rebooted several times and only logged in as `root` each time, but got the same error.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop my home dir from being tied up so I can encrypt it?

```
INFO:  Checking disk space, this may take a few moments.  Please be patient.
INFO:  Checking for open files in /home/will
INFO:  The following files are in use:

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
systemd     1 root   19r  FIFO    0,8      0t0  1384 pipe
systemd     1 root   22u  FIFO   0,15      0t0  1388 /run/dmeventd-server
systemd     1 root   23u  FIFO   0,15      0t0  1389 /run/dmeventd-client
systemd     1 root   24u  FIFO   0,15      0t0  1391 /run/systemd/initctl/fifo
systemd-l 134 root   21r  FIFO   0,15      0t0 11459 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
login     138 root    6w  FIFO   0,15      0t0 11459 /run/systemd/sessions/c1.ref
lsof      309 root    1w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13379 pipe
lsof      309 root    4w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13380 pipe
lsof      309 root    5r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13381 pipe
sed       310 root    0r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13379 pipe
lsof      311 root    3r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13380 pipe
lsof      311 root    6w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 13381 pipe

ERROR:  Cannot proceed.
```

Comment: What's your current directory? It looks like you may be running the encrypt command while in that directory. Apart from that possibility I don't see anything that's using `/home/will` in the `lsof` output.

Comment: I can confirm the current directory is `/` when the command is run

Comment: Do you have any filesystems mounted in a subdirectory of your home directory?

Comment: I do not. This is a brand new Arch install that's fairly generic. One partition `/dev/sda1` and nothing in `/etc/fstab` except `/`